# How to check the condition $E(\bar{K})[n] \subseteq E(K)$ for pairing $e_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elliptic-curves

When constructing the Weil pairing $e_n$, it is required that $E(\bar{K})[n] \subseteq E(K)$,
where $E$ is a curve over field $K$, $\bar{K}$ is the field's algebraic closure and $G[n]$ are all the elements $g \in G$ with $ng = 0$. How does one check this condition. Are there curves $E$ that satisfy this condition for all $n$ or do we need to check for each $n$ individually?

Comment: you are incorrect about 'it is required'. Reread whatever source you are using. (presumably $E$ is an elliptic curve...)

Comment: Maybe "it is required" was a bit mistated. In the source material "Elliptic curves number theory and cryptography" by Lawrence C. Washington, in chapter 11.2 (Weil pairing), this condition is assumed for pairing constructed on $\bar{K}$ to return relevant values in $K$, so that the algebraic closure is only an unnecessary abstraction. Could you point me to some material that doesn't require this (or explains it in some more explicit way)?

Comment: I think I see. If your point is that you want that the values of the Weil pairing $e_n$ to be $K$ rational, you need only that $K$ contains the $n$th roots of unity (char $K\not| n$), and not necessarily the stronger condition that the $n$th torsion of $E$ is $K$ rational. For a stupid example, take $n=2$ (and char $K$ not $2$); then the ell curve $y^2=f(x)$ ($f$ separable) will have its $2$ rational points iff $f$ splits. Yet the Weil pairing $e_2$ always takes values in $\{\pm 1\}$ . BTW, the stronger condition (which you wanted) implies the weaker because the pairing is Gal equivariant.